# Handling of Incorrect Value for type Integer as RequestParam in REST API in Spring Boot Application

Tags: rest, spring-boot, integer

I have a problem with one of the negative scenarios of Testing an API.
I have a spring boot application with one RestController which takes in a RequestParam("id") and i return back the same id along with HttpStatus.OK.

When i hit GET API like : http://localhost:8080/Temp/getInteger?id=%23abcd
the value that gets assigned to id is 43981 which i don't understand how it got assigned.

Ideally i don't expect this String to be converted into an Integer, Can someone help me with this?

Code:

```
@RestController 
@RequestMapping("/Temp")
public class TempController{
  @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, path= "/getInteger")
  public ResponseEntity<Object> getInteger(@RequestParam("id") Integer id){
    return new ResponseEntity(id,HttpStatus.OK);
  }
}
```

Request:

```
http://localhost:8080/Temp/getInteger?id=%23abcd
```

Output :

```
Http Status : 200 OK
Response Body : 43981
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From UTF-8 URL Encoded Characters: %23 is # and
from hexadecimal number system:
abcd is 43981

So it can be cast to INT. You can add a letter "e" and get a new number 703710. If you want to avoid it you need to add validation.